# Keydown event only working when click happens before

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a calculator based on click events, in addition I'm now trying to sync up keydown events.

The keydown event is firing a console log but won't actually go on to compute the code.

In the instance below if the user has clicked on some numbers the display updates accordingly and when they click the delete button the last character entered is removed. However if I click the delete button on my keyboard instead of clicking the onscreen button nothing happens. Unless! I click the delete button first then the keydown event fires.

```
//Update display on click
addEventListener('click', e => {
  calculate(e);
});

//Update display on keydown event
addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  calculate(e);
});

//Fire calculate function removing last character use has added to display
let calculate = (e) => {
if (e.target.id === "back" || e.keyCode === 8) {
console.log("hello");
displayArea.innerHTML = displayArea.innerHTML.substring(0, displayArea.innerHTML.length - 1);
}
```

Any advice?

https://jsfiddle.net/qjenxfLd/3/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this part like this:

```
if (e.target.id === "back" || e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
   console.log("hello");
   displayArea.innerHTML = displayArea.innerHTML.substring(0, 
   displayArea.innerHTML.length - 1);
   displayValue = Number(displayValue.toString().substring(0, 
   displayValue.toString().length - 1));
}
```

and this one like this:

```
 } else {
     if (e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 46)
    {
      buttonNumber = Number(e.target.innerText);
      displayValue = buttonNumber;
      displayArea.innerHTML += displayValue;
    }             
    displayArea.innerHTML = Number(displayArea.innerHTML);
 }
}
if (e.target.id === "AC") {
```

and now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you're on the right track, to make not to be confused rename `<button>DEL</button>` to `<button>⬅</button>` then bind the following

```
⬅ to keyCode 8 or Backspace // delete 1 number, already binded
AC to keyCode 46 or Delete // delete all number
```

To bind `AC` to `DEL` on keyboard replace

```
if (e.target.id === "AC")
```

with

```
if (e.target.id === "AC" || e.keyCode === 46)
```

it need `.blur()` after button clicked to make sure there are no duplicate event `click` and `keydown`

```
addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.blur();
  calculate(e);
});
```

make sure the following lines only executed only on `click` event, replace

```
else {
buttonNumber = Number(e.target.innerText);
displayValue = buttonNumber;
```

with

```
else if (e.target.className) {
buttonNumber = Number(e.target.innerText);
displayValue = buttonNumber;
```

bonus:
previously I created  calculator function, it bind click and all keyboard event (number, operator)

```js
let n1, n2, operator;
let operations = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};

let calculate = (e) => {
  if (e.target.className == 'item') { // click event
    e.target.blur()
    handleInput(e.target.textContent.trim())
  } else { // keydown event
    handleInput(e.key)
  }
}

let handleInput = (str) => {
  if(str == undefined) return
  let displayed = displayArea.textContent;
  if (isNaN(str)) { // handle not number
    if (str == '.' && !displayed.includes('.')) {
      displayArea.textContent += '.'
    } else if (str == 'AC' || str == 'Delete') {
      displayArea.textContent = '0'
      n1 = n2 = ''
    } else if (str == '⬅' || str == 'Backspace') {
      displayArea.textContent = displayed.length < 2 ?
        '0' : displayed.slice(0, -1)
      if (operator) n2 = parseFloat(displayArea.textContent)
    } else if ((str == '=' || str == 'Enter') && n1 && n2) {
      console.log(operator, n1, n2)
      n1 = operations[operator](n1, n2)
      displayArea.textContent = n1
      n2 = '';
      operator = ''

    } else {
      n1 = parseFloat(displayArea.textContent)
      str = str.replace('÷', '/').replace('×', '*')
      operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/'].includes(str) ? str : '';
    }
  } else { // handle number
    if (operator) {
      if (!n2) displayArea.textContent = str
      else displayArea.textContent += str
      n2 = parseFloat(displayArea.textContent)
    } else {
      if (displayArea.textContent == '0') displayArea.textContent = str
      else displayArea.textContent += str
    }
  }
}

let displayArea = document.querySelector('#result-display');
displayArea.textContent = '0';

['click', 'keydown'].forEach(a =>
  addEventListener(a, e => {
    calculate(e);
  })
);
```

```css
body{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;flex-direction:row;width:100%;height:100vh;font-size:18px}
.container{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;width:275px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)}
.sub-container{display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center}
.display{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:flex-end;width:100%;height:65px;color:#fff;background-color:#000}
#result-display{margin-right:8%}
.button-grid{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;width:100%}
.item{width:68px;height:65px;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:center;align-items:center;color:#000;font-size:18px;caret-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
#equals{width:204px}
button{width:100%;height:100%}
#equals{background-color:orange}
[data-type="nonNumber"]{background-color:lightgray}
#AC{background-color:#FCFCFC}
footer{width:100%;background-color:gray}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="display">
     <p id="result-display"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-grid">
      <div> <button class="item"> 7 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 8 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 9 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> &divide; </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 4 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 5 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 6 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> &times; </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 1 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 2 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 3 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> - </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> 0 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> . </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> AC </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> &plus; </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> &equals; </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="item"> ⬅ </button> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```